# Cannot type file paths on any Open File Dialogs?

Tags: linux-mint, thunar, nemo

There is no way I can type/paste a file path when I use some Open File dialog:

[image]

There is not right click option or anything. I use linux Mint XFCE 19.1:

```
linux@linux:~$ uname -a
Linux linux 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I had installed `nemo` and set it as the default file manager, then I uninstalled, but the Open File Dialog still does not allow me to type the file path.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the file dialog is based on the Gnome toolkit (Gtk), then you should be able to toggle the *location popup* using keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

See [GtkFileChooserWidget: The “location-popup” signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserWidget.html#GtkFileChooserWidget-location-popup)

Comment: BTW Ctrl+L is also used in Nautilus and some other file browsers.

Comment: Plasma KDE Open Folder dialog works the same. Thanks for sharing! How is the best method to discover these features?

Comment: @LogoS the best method to discover these features is right here :-/

Comment: it's 2023, and we still need to google for things like this. I mean: I have a dialog box and the file path in the buffer, i want to pick that file, but the "Open File" dialog doesn't have any tips on how to to that.. Sometimes we need a useful UI, not only "beautiful". 

By the way, thanks for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>!!